# xdg-open chooses the wrong app

Tags: gpio, node.js, sudo

In a nodeJs app I have:

//----------------------------

var execSync = require ('child_process'). execSync;

function puts (error, stdout, stderr) {console.log (stdout)}

function execute (comm) {execSync (comm, puts); }

execute ("xdg-open file:///home/pi/index.html");

//----------------------------------

This works fine when I perform:
node myApp.js
causes the desired page to open in Chrome.

But:
sudo node myApp.js
opens the page in Geany !!

If I log in as "root" it is also Geany that opens !!

Many nodeJs modules (which use GPIO) unfortunately require the use of 'sudo'!

What do I do?

Comment: To put it simple: 
sudo xdg-open file:///home/pi/index.html  (from terminal)
opens Geany not Chrome.
I read somewhere that deleting: ~/.config/mimeapps.list
will solve the problem.  
It did not!!!!

Comment: Could you format the code in your question so that it's distinguishable from regular text?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the default application for `root` to the same value as for `pi`:

```
filetype=$(xdg-mime query filetype file:///home/pi/index.html)
defaultapp=$(xdg-mime query default $filetype) # query as pi
sudo xdg-mime default $defaultapp $filetype    # set as root
```

Alternatively, executing `sudo -u pi xdg-open file:///home/pi/index.html` should use the settings of the `pi` user when opening the file.

Finally, there's a whole bunch of tools you could use instead of `xdg-open`, e.g. `mimeo`.

Comment: Thanks.
Your first suggestion : In which file do I put this?
Your second suggestion : It does not work for me.
The last one: I will look into it.

Thanks again / Poul C